macOS change Native TextReplacment list from terminal
Good afternoon everyone, recently I had here a question in which I was helped to solve my question about adding a new key-value pair to text replacement on macOS.
Now I've found a way to do it with just one command using the terminal:
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems -array-add '{on=1;replace="uuuuuu";with="yyyyy";}'

Then I enter the following command to check if a new pair has been added to the general array:
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems

Here we get a list of all pairs, and here we see that our pair has been successfully added:
},
    {
    on = 1;
    replace = uuuuuu;
    with = yyyyy;
}
)

And in the end, I ask for the following command to apply the changes:
 killall -u $(whoami) cfprefsd 

But after overloading the system when entering the command
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems

The pair I added earlier is no longer there!
Tell me, is it possible to add new pairs to replace the text in this way? If so, how to apply the list changes?
I will be grateful for any help!
